# Dimensional/Domain Change in "Generalized Negative Reciprocity"?

Tags: behavioral-economics, altruism

[Generalized (Positive) Reciprocity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocity_(social_psychology)) says that if A helps B, B will help C. Many studies have shown that this behavior exists in different settings (real life, field and lab experiments). Studies also show that the "task/dimension/domain" between A/B and B/C can be different. For example, A helps B with a computer problem and B gives more in a dictator game.

I'm more interested in Generalized Negative Reciprocity. If A is unkind to B, B will be unkind to C. Obviously the underlying mechanisms in the positive and negative versions are different. Studies have shown (e.g. [Gray, et al. 2014](https://doi.org/10.1037/a0031047) and [Strang, et al. 2016](https://doi.org/10.1038/srep22316)) that if the "task/dimension/domain" is similar, people reciprocate negatively. A gives little in dictator game to B and B will do the same in a dictator game to C. But what if the dimensions are different. Like A gives B a bad task instead of a good one, will B also give little to C ina dictator game (compared to a B that received a good task).

Do you guys know any papers that deal with this research question? I spent weeks reading literature in this area but I cannot believe that nobody tried it out.

Update 1: I actually found something. Zitek et al. 2010 let participants think about unfair situations in their past and they observe less pro-social behavior in different experiments.

Nevertheless, I would appreciate additional resources. I'm going through papers citing Zitek.

> Social modeling could explain past research showing a relationship
> between being the victim of selfish behavior and acting selfishly in
> the same domain (e.g., Austin & Walster, 1975; Moschetti & Kues, 1978;
> Zitek et al., 2007); perhaps people who have been the victims of
> uneven monetary distributions, for example, simply imitate such unfair
> behavior when it is their own turn to distribute money or believe that
> such behavior is more normative. We found, however, that when people
> pondered times when life was unfair to them—recalling slights in a
> wide variety of domains—they were subsequently less likely to help an
> experimenter with an additional task, even though none of them had
> recalled a time when they asked for help but did not receive it.

### References

Gray, K., Ward, A. F., & Norton, M. I. (2014). Paying it forward: Generalized reciprocity and the limits of generosity. *Journal of experimental psychology: General, 143*(1), 247. doi: [10.1037/a0031047](https://doi.org/10.1037/a0031047)

Strang, S., Grote, X., Kuss, K., Park, S. Q., & Weber, B. (2016). Generalized negative reciprocity in the dictator game–how to interrupt the chain of unfairness. *Scientific reports, 6*, 22316. doi: [10.1038/srep22316](https://doi.org/10.1038/srep22316)

Zitek, E. M., Jordan, A. H., Monin, B., & Leach, F. R. (2010). Victim entitlement to behave selfishly. Journal of personality and social psychology, 98(2), 245. [link](https://psycnet.apa.org/record/2010-00584-006)

// edit: Thanks to Chris Rogers for adding the references!